# Impossible to click on element with selenium when browser not on mac current space

Tags: python, selenium, browser, click

I'm using selenium in python to control a website. I use Firefox. I want to click on a mat-select element.

When Firefox is on one of my Mac used spaces (or desktops), all works fine.
When I switch to another space to work on other full screen applications, I get this error :

```
s
Stacktrace:
WebDriverError@chrome://remote/content/shared/webdriver/Errors.jsm:183:5
ElementClickInterceptedError@chrome://remote/content/shared/webdriver/Errors.jsm:282:5
webdriverClickElement@chrome://remote/content/marionette/interaction.js:166:11
interaction.clickElement@chrome://remote/content/marionette/interaction.js:125:11
clickElement@chrome://remote/content/marionette/actors/MarionetteCommandsChild.jsm:203:24
receiveMessage@chrome://remote/content/marionette/actors/MarionetteCommandsChild.jsm:91:31
```

My code that works if the browser is in my current work space on Mac:

```
xpath='//mat-select[@placeholder="Duration"]'
WebDriverWait(driver, 2).until(presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, xpath)))
element = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, xpath)
print(element.is_enabled()) # return True
print(element.is_displayed()) # return True if browser in my space, False otherwise
element.click()
```

My brother is maximized, I've try many things read on forums, like using javascript to scroll, to move the cursor etc. without any success.

Do you have any idea on how to click this button?

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! Can you share the link to the page, code that you've tried and exact error stack trace ?

Comment: Thanks @cruisepandey, I've updated my post! The page is a private one

Comment: I think I have found something, I have a pointer-events becoming none when I put my browser outside of my space. I've tried to change this property thanks to javascript code without success. Any idea ?
My code :
```driver.execute_script("arguments[0].style['pointer-events'] = 'auto';", element)```

Comment: I've changed the pointer-event and it solved my issue ! I'm stil curious to know why this property can depend on whether the browser is on my space or not haha